# Create new sheet and create table within

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create new worksheets, name the new worksheets, add columns to the worksheets, and then make a table in each new spreadsheet, all in a workbook that has one sheet to begin with. My code doesn't work, but to see where I am with this so far:

```
Sub Create_Sheets()

Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_VALUE"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_VALUE"

Dim Table As ListObject
Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("VA_NAME")

Table.ListColumns.Add 1
Table.HeaderRowRange(1) = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 2
Table.HeaderRowRange(2) = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 3
Table.HeaderRowRange(3) = "L1_ATTR_TEMP_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 4
Table.HeaderRowRange(4) = "L1_ATTR_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 5
Table.HeaderRowRange(5) = "L1_ATTR_VALUE"

Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("VA_VALUE")
Table.ListColumns.Add 1
Table.HeaderRowRange(1) = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 2
Table.HeaderRowRange(2) = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 3
Table.HeaderRowRange(3) = "L1_ATTR_TEMP_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 4
Table.HeaderRowRange(4) = "L1_ATTR_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 5
Table.HeaderRowRange(5) = "L1_ATTR_VALUE"

Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("CE_NAME")
Table.ListColumns.Add 1
Table.HeaderRowRange(1) = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 2
Table.HeaderRowRange(2) = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 3
Table.HeaderRowRange(3) = "L1_ATTR_TEMP_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 4
Table.HeaderRowRange(4) = "L1_ATTR_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 5
Table.HeaderRowRange(5) = "L1_ATTR_VALUE"

Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("CE_VALUE")
Table.ListColumns.Add 1
Table.HeaderRowRange(1) = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 2
Table.HeaderRowRange(2) = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Table.ListColumns.Add 3
Table.HeaderRowRange(3) = "L1_ATTR_TEMP_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 4
Table.HeaderRowRange(4) = "L1_ATTR_NAME"
Table.ListColumns.Add 5
Table.HeaderRowRange(5) = "L1_ATTR_VALUE"

Columns.AutoFit
```

I would prefer that the code recognize the sheet name (i.e, "VA_NAME") rather than by "Sheet2, Sheet3" and so on. I know "Set Table = Sheet1.ListObjects("VA_NAME")" is far more than likely my problem, as this relies on "Sheet(X)" convention, but doing Sheets("VA_NAME").ListObjects doesn't work. Is there a quick fix to this, or is what I'm asking against VBA's rules?

Thanks, all!

UPDATE: It's occurred to me that my posted code assumes that tables already exist, and that is not the case.  I have added new code to create actual tables, but without named columns:

```
Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1"), , xlNo).Name = "VA_NAME"
Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1"), , xlNo).Name = "VA_VALUE"
Sheet4.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1"), , xlNo).Name = "CE_NAME"
Sheet5.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1"), , xlNo).Name = "CE_VALUE"
```

My order of operations should be Create Named Sheets --> Create Named Columns --> Create Tables from Columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I doubt this is the most intuitive way to go about creating named sheets with named tables and columns, this is what I did (I am still very open to suggestions):

```
Sub Create_Sheets()

Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_VALUE"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_VALUE"
```

End Sub

Sub Create_PARCEL_ATTR_Tables()

```
Sheets("VA_NAME").Select
Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$1"), , xlNo).Name = "VA_NAME"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Select
Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$1"), , xlNo).Name = "VA_VALUE"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Select
Sheet4.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$1"), , xlNo).Name = "CE_NAME"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Select
Sheet5.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$E$1"), , xlNo).Name = "CE_VALUE"
```

End Sub

Sub Create_PARCEL_ATTR_COLUMNS()

```
Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("A1").Value = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("B1").Value = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("C1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_TEMP_NAME"
Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("D1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_NAME"
Sheets("VA_NAME").Range("E1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_VALUE"
Sheets("VA_NAME").Columns.AutoFit

Sheets("VA_VALUE").Range("A1").Value = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Range("B1").Value = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Range("C1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_TEMP_NAME"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Range("D1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_NAME"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Range("E1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_VALUE"
Sheets("VA_VALUE").Columns.AutoFit

Sheets("CE_NAME").Range("A1").Value = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Range("B1").Value = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Range("C1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_TEMP_NAME"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Range("D1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_NAME"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Range("E1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_VALUE"
Sheets("CE_NAME").Columns.AutoFit

Sheets("CE_VALUE").Range("A1").Value = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Range("B1").Value = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Range("C1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_TEMP_NAME"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Range("D1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_NAME"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Range("E1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_VALUE"
Sheets("CE_VALUE").Columns.AutoFit
```

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 0):

If you code above works, this would shorten it and make it less cumbersome.

```
Sub Create_PARCEL_Stuff()

Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "VA_VALUE"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_NAME"
Sheets.Add.Name = "CE_VALUE"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "NAME OF YOUR SHEET WITH DATA" Then
            'Do Nothing
        Else
            ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets("Name of source sheet").Range("$A$1:$E$1"), , xlNo).Name = ws.Name
            ws.Range("A1").Value = "SOURCE_SEQ_NBR"
            ws.Range("B1").Value = "L1_PARCEL_NBR"
            ws.Range("C1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_TEMP_NAME"
            ws.Range("D1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_NAME"
            ws.Range("E1").Value = "L1_ATTRIB_VALUE"
            ws.Columns.AutoFit
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Your given code creates the columns and table for "CE_VALUE" but won't go further, citing "The worksheet range for the table data must be on the same sheet as the table being created." Is this because the active worksheet isn't changed in the code?

Comment: This does less now than it did before your last fix. When I try this on a blank sheet and replace "NAME OF YOUR SHEET WITH DATA" and "Name of source sheet," it still stops after "CE_VALUE." I should've noted earlier that the contents of the existing sheet aren't relevant to this, and the only significance that sheet has is its use of the name Sheet1.

Comment: What is the source for your table you are adding?  That second part of `ListObjects.Add` is for your source.